# Deserialise JSON to C# array, where index is in the property name

Tags: c#, mongodb, json.net, servicestack-text

Could anyone provide their approach for deserializing the following JSON

```
{
  "i": 5
  "b0": "ABC",
  "b1": "DEF",
  "b2": "GHI",
  "s0": "SABC",
  "s1": "SDEF",
  "s2": "SGHI",
}
```

into a class in C# to provide the same structure as this

```
class Example {
    public int Index {get;set;}
    public string[] B {get;set;}
    public string[] S {get;set;}
}

var b = new [] {"ABC", "DEF", "GHI"}
var s = new [] {"SABC", "SDEF", "SGHI"}
```

I generally use ServiceStack.Text, but Json.Net approach or even a BsonDocument from the MongoDb provider is fine.

Comment: What have you tried already? You can enumerate the tokens manually via something like `JObject.Parse` in JSON.NET, have you given this a go?

Comment: I'd deserialise into a dictionary<string, string> and then extract the values. What am I missing?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Good question. The array isn't quite as clean as the sample. Other properties included are included such as "i", "s0", "s1". Have updated the question with a more relevant sample

Answer (score 1):

Could use a `JToken` and use `.Values()` then `.ToArray()`:

```
var json = "{\r\n  \"b0\": \"ABC\",\r\n  \"b1\": \"DEF\",\r\n  \"b2\": \"GHI\",\r\n}";

var token = JToken.Parse(json);

var b = token.Values().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

This one solution might be useful too:

```
         public class Example
          {
            public int Index { get; set; }
            public string[] B { get; set; }
            public string[] S { get; set; }
          }   

               var strData = @"{'i': 5, 'b0': 'ABC','b1': 'DEF', 'b2': 'GHI', 's0': 'SABC', 's1': 'SDEF', 's2': 'SGHI',}";
               var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(strData).Values().ToList();
               Example result = new Example();
               result.Index = data.Values().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Path == "i").Value<int>();
                result.B = data.Values().Where(x => x.Path.StartsWith("b")).Select(x => x.Value<string>()).ToArray();
                result.S = data.Values().Where(x => x.Path.StartsWith("s")).Select(x => x.Value<string>()).ToArray();
```

there is solution for dynamic name of arrays, but string array is not the best type in this case:

```
   public class Example
    {
        public int Index { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string[]> Data { set; get; }
    }


            var s = @"{'i': 5, 'b0': 'ABC','b1': 'DEF', 'b2': 'GHI', 's0': 'SABC', 's1': 'SDEF', 's2': 'SGHI',}";
           var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(s).Values().ToList();
            Example result = new Example();
            result.Index = data.Values().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Path == "i").Value<int>();
            result.Data = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
            var stringData = data.Values().Where(x => x.Path != "i").ToList();

            stringData.ForEach(x =>
            {
                var key = x.Path[0].ToString();
                if (!result.Data.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    result.Data.Add(key,  new string[0]);
                }

                var currentValue = result.Data[key].ToList();
                currentValue.Add(x.Value<string>());
                result.Data[key] = currentValue.ToArray();
             });
```

Comment: This is the only way I can think of too - if you want to use a class

Comment: @chris iI might be used Dictionary for dynamic named arrays. But PO noted specific class structure and I followed it

Comment: I know, I'm agreeing with you :)